# Nested fragment in a tab inside?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have three tabs in a fragment. And I want to create each tab in a new fragment. I show the [google code](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html). Now, my code can create the tabs, but doesn't show anything in the content of each tab.

My main fragment xml:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

How i create the tabs:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
    mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(activity);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"), IconsFragment.class, null);

    return mTabHost;
}
```

In IconsFragment, I inflate the view normally as normal fragment. But I don't see any item in this fragment. How I can create the tabs with nested fragments?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the android.R.id.tabcontent name colapsed with the an FragmentTabHost name component.

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

java

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);

mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1"), GalleryMyIconsFragment.class, null);

mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2"), GalleryMyIconsFragment.class, null);
```